# Editing the single.php file breaks my wordpress website, even after I restore the original

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I edited the single.php file of the child theme of my WordPress installation , but kept the original.
Before amending, the website looked like this from the frontend:

[Original appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPNY0.jpg)
After editing, the website now looked like this:
[Broken template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5tdo.jpg)  This is broken.  However, I restored the original file, but the website still looks like this.  I have deleted the theme altogether, and recreated it, but it still looks like this.  It only reverts back to normal when I use the original parent theme. Could anyone please help me to identify what is happening, and how to fix it so that it looks like the original appearance but with the child theme.  Many thanks

Comment: make sure you clear your cache (browser and server side as well, if any)

Comment: Also make sure that when you restore your "original" it wasn't accidentally changed either. A single untracked change where you delete one closing bracket could be hard to find and also create these issues.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  @Blurfus, I've used a new browser but the problem persists.  I have also cleared the WP content "cache" folder, but the problem is still there. Is there anywhere else I might need to clear cache?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 I've deleted the single.php file altogether, so my child theme no longer has one but relies on the single.php of the parent theme. Problem still persists.  The problem only goes away when I manually change altogether to the parent theme.

Comment: I have also deactivated each of the plugins one at a time, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I managed to resolve the issue by uploading a working version of the child theme via FTP, and that appears to work. I suspect that it might be a permissions issue.